# callback after getJSON in for loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, getjson

So i'm doing a getJSON request in a for loop.
In the getJSON function callback I push the values into a global array.

Now accessing that global array outside the for loop is not possible due the fact getJSON is async i read...

I tried making flags and other callback functions but it looks like even the for loop ends faster (even with je getJSON function insde the for loop) than the getJSON requests..

```
function initMap(){

// Address value variables
var country;
var city;
var addresses = [];
var locations = [];

// Google maps variables
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId: 'terrain',
    scrollwheel: false,
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    draggable: true
};
var marker;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

// Get country city values
$('li.deal-itinerary-item').each(function(){
    country = $(this).data('country');
    city = $(this).data('city');
    if( country && city ){
        addresses.push(country + ' ' + city);
    }
});

var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas')[0], myOptions);

for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {

        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

        locations.push({lat: p.lat, lng: p.lng});

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);

    });

}

// CONSOLE LOG NOT WORKING HERE
console.log(locations);

map.fitBounds(bounds);

zoomChangeBoundsListener = 
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
    if (this.getZoom()){
        this.setZoom(6);
    }
});
setTimeout(function(){google.maps.event.removeListener(zoomChangeBoundsListener)}, 2000);

};
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

So first the variables, then i get Country name and City name out of data attribute on divs inside the dom. Then I itterate over the addresses to get the lat/lng values for the markers (and the polylines).
If i console.log the locations variable at the end, it shows an empty array in the console, but when I click the array is filled (probably cause the array gets filled after displaying it)..

P.S. Since I can't yet post images, the console.log() displays just [ ]
and when i click on the array it show the objects just fine...

```
0  Object { lat=53.3498053,  lng=-6.2603097}
1  Object { lat=53.3498053,  lng=-6.2603097}
2  Object { lat=53.3498053,  lng=-6.2603097}
3  Object { lat=53.717856,  lng=-6.3560985}
4  Object { lat=54.5982897,  lng=-5.8925882}
5  Object { lat=53.59944249999999,  lng=-7.850193999999999}
6  Object { lat=54.6541972,  lng=-8.110546}
7  Object { lat=54.9558392,  lng=-7.7342787}
```

Any help on this is highly appriciated since im stuck on this since yesterday...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var count_getJSONs_done = 0;
for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {

        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

        locations.push({lat: p.lat, lng: p.lng});

        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);

    })
      .always(function() {
         count_getJSONs_done++;
         if (count_getJSONs_done == addresses.length) // the last getJSON in the loop is completed
           processLocations();
      });

}
```

According to http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, section: "Callback Function Queues", the `.always` callback will be invoked after `success` handler of `getJSON`.

**Updated:**
Notice, that this code works even if some of the `getJSON` have failed.

Comment: Notice, that this code works even some of the `getJSON` fail.

Comment: This seems to be in the good direction, tho this function gets repeated for each for loop...?

Comment: `.always` callback is called after each `getJSON`: and as first -- your callback, then `.always` callback. Or more precisely: `.always` is called after each `getJSON` is completed. That means the loop can be already finished when `processLocations` is executed.

Comment: Isn't there a way to just continue coding with the filled array..? Like a callback after the for loop..? I have a strange feeling im overlooking something here...

Comment: btw @jacek, whats different about the default callback functon inside getJSON function and the .always callback..?

Comment: The default callback is invoked only when the server says "everything has gone well". Always is invoked always -- no matter what the server says.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I think thats not what im looking for however when I console log in the locations array in the processLocations function I do get a nicely filled array..
Now what I need is a function where i have the filled array and which doesnt repeat anymore..

Comment: Even if there was something like "a callback after loop", it woundn't work here. Because the loop **only** runs `getJSON`s and the `getJSON`s live their own life. Like a teacher saying ,,do your homework'' to every student in the classroom: then it's a student's task; the teacher just wants the result, he/she doesn't care when or even if each student will do its job. `getJSON`s are the students;)

Comment: "a function where i have the filled array and which doesnt repeat anymore" -- I don't understand... `processLocations` will be invoked only once -- after completion of the last `getJSON`

Comment: Oh I see.. Thanks for the example! Its clear now yet the if doesnt get triggerd, and if I log the X and addresses.length they are both 8, so if I correct the if statement to 'x == addresses.length' it gets executed 8 times, yet the array is filled (or logged) correctly this way.. So we are almost there I guess..

Comment: PS there are cases this callback processLocations gets executed 7 times..  But in no case it runs just once..

Comment: I corrected the code... The first version wrong... Now `processLocation` shoud be invoked only once. I missed that I can't use `x` to count how many `getJSON` have been completed.

Comment: I was on the same way, tho X is sort of a counter no? But this code works! Thanks a mili!

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic

```
for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x]+'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {

    var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);

    locations.push({lat: p.lat, lng: p.lng});

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);

    if(locations.length == addresses.length){ // all locations gathered
        console.dir(locations)
    }
});
```

}

Comment: If one of `getJSON` fails, `console.dir(locations)` will not be executed.